# US citizen traveling to Vietnam with unexpired Vietnam passport

Tags: visas, passports, us-citizens, vietnam

I recently became US citizen and going to travel back to Vietnam. Is it possible to travel to Vietnam with an unexpired Vietnam passport instead of applying for a Vietnam visa?

Comment: Does Vietnam allow dual citizenship?

Comment: Note that, as a US citizen, you'll need to use your US passport to enter the US. (And, presumably, need to show it when you're checking in for your flight in Vietnam, so the airline knows you're allowed to enter the US without a visa.)

Comment: @phoog - yes, but only under certain limited circumstances; I can't remember exactly what they are.

Comment: Do you still have Vietnamese citizenship? Or you had to give it up, and you are just left with the passport?

Comment: I am only left with my Vietnam passport. I believe I gave up my Vietnam citizenship when I became US citizenship. My Vietnam passport is still valid

Comment: @AndyTran: Reading http://moj.gov.vn/vbpq/en/lists/vn%20bn%20php%20lut/view_detail.aspx?itemid=10451 , I don't see anything that says acquisition of a foreign nationality causes loss of Vienamese nationality.

Comment: If you did actually give up your nationality then your passport is no longer valid despite it not having expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **unexpired** Vietnam Passport will **allow** entry back into Vietnam. Assuming you still have a valid citizenship in Vietnam

Comment: If the holder of the passport has lost Vietnamese citizenship, though, the passport is invalid even if it has not expired.